# Count table rows from another page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count table rows from a html page. I am currently using this:

```
<div id="count_rows"></div>
<script>
$(function() {
var c_rows  =  $('#toCount tbody tr').length;
$( "#count_rows" ).append( "number of rows: " + c_rows );
});
</script>
```

This works great when the script is on the same page, but lets say I have a structure like this:

index.html -> where I want the count result.
table.html -> where I have the table.

How can I count the values from another page? Also, table.html will have different table rows based on sessions.
For example user X after login will have on table.html a table with 5 rows and user Y will have  on table.html a table with 10 rows.

Thank you

Comment: JS can only work with the DOM that's currently loaded. If you want to know how many table rows are in another page you'll need to make an AJAX request to load that page, then count the `tr` in whatever table is relevant. However in that scenario querying a central datastore would make much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, isn’t there another way beside querying the database? I wanna show this numbers on a menu and that would run the query every time the user does a refresh.